# Convert string to decimal to string and back to decimal

Tags: vb.net, string, type-conversion, decimal

I want to convert a string to a decimal then to a string and then to a decimal again.

I tried:

```
Dim s As String = "0.7655"

CDec(sDec).ToString("0.00")  'results in: 7653,00
CDec(sDec).ToString 'results in: 7648
CDec(sDec).ToString("N") 'results in: 7.653,00
```

So none of these work!

Is there no easy function to just convert the exact decimal to its string representation again? Seems like too much work for such a simple task!

Preferably without formatting the string, because in that case I seem to know beforehand how many characters the resulting string should have.
After converting it to string, I also want to convert it back to a decimal again.

Comment: they do work but you'll need to specify the culture code. A quick search on SO will bring up a lot of solutions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your current culture the decimal separator might be a comma instead of a dot. Using the invariant culture will always use the dot:

```
Dim s As String = "0.7655"

Dim decValue As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(s, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Console.WriteLine(decValue.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to acheive your answer by using the Parse method.

```
    Dim s As String = "0.7655"
    Dim c As Decimal = Nothing

    c = Decimal.Parse(s)

    Console.WriteLine(c)
```

You can then use the `ToString` method to convert back to a string.